# A very small riddle

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

> My prefix is given to very dedicated people
> My infix is an important figure for star worshippers
> My suffix is only visible for a limited time each day
> **What am I?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Dram

My prefix is given to very dedicated people

> The title of **"Dr"** is generally awarded to those who complete a PhD degree, showing a dedication to their subject

My infix is an important figure for star worshippers

> [**Ra**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ra) was the ancient Egyptian deity of the Sun.

My suffix is only visible for a limited time each day

> **A.M.** (twelve hours to be exact)

Title

> A **dram** is a *small* drink of whisky (or another spirit).

Comment: That's correct! As additional trivia, rot13(N qenz vf bar bs gur fznyyrfg havgf gb zrnfher syhvqf, vg pbeerfcbaqf gb 1/8gu bs na bhapr (be nobhg n grnfcbba))